# Is there a hotkey modifier for G that sets rather than moves the coordinate?

Tags: modeling, transforms, vertices, shortcut

Is there a modifier for the G hotkey that **sets** the vertex global X/Y/Z location, rather than moves it relative to the current location?  (Something like G**G** X 12.5 to directly set the global X coord to 12.5).

I'm using blender to render a number of simple 2d textured shapes (orthographic projection) that directly face the camera.

I add many shapes to a single blend file so I can position them relative to each other and then render them using a script.

At present I have to position vertices by clicking on the Info panel, Transform section, X,Y,Z coordinate textboxes and manually typing.

I find this quite slow when I have to do this 20 plus times.

I can use vertex snapping (to other objects) sometimes, but this is no use for vertex locations that are not identical (ie offset).

This would be also useful in the UV Editor.  I would like to be able to select a vertex and simply set it's U or V in a similar way (ie to line the vertex up with the edge corners of a simple quad texture).

I've read the online documents for the Transform keyboard shortcuts and nothing like this is mentioned.

Comment: You can input fractions - i.e 12.5/whatever_the_x_coordinate_is_now. Other than this it's not supported yet. You would have to script your own modal operator and call it with assigned hotkey.

Comment: If you could start at 0,0,0 you could use G followed by X or Y or Z and a number to go to that location. (ctrl G x 7 should move 7 along the x axis and so if it starts at 0 it will go to 7)  Any use or have I misunderstood?

Comment: The Beachdancer, I use that all the time when I am at the origin.  Question is how to do this when not at the origin?  My blend file has many objects positioned relative to each other.

Comment: Jerryno,  I don't undestand how fractions help.  If I'm at X=6 and want to set X=9, typing "G X 9/6" would just move 1.5 along X wouldn't it?  Also, this has no effect when I actually try it (blender 2.74).

Comment: @Ash To use expressions in modal transform operators you have to type `=` first. So for example: `G` +  `X` + `=` + `9/6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I think the closest you can get now (without some python custom operator stuff) is resetting to the origin (<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>) before moving the object. So:

1. <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>
2. <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> `X coordinate`
3. <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> `Y coordinate`
4. <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> `Z coordinate`

Comment: Yes, maybe what I ask for is not really in the Blender philosophy, ie. it's more of a CAD feature.  Still I think there are many users like me who try to use Blender for precision work.    When I learn more about the API I might even try creating a proper add-on for it. (I know of that tinyCAD add-on but it fails in 2.74 when I try enabling it)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is move the 3d cursor to the coordinates, then snap the selection to the cursor.